# I'm getting an TypeError when trying to use read(\n) in a python script when I'm pulling data from a file

Tags: python

I think I'm missing something super basic here, so proper heckling is okay... I'm using a custom lib here and just trying to get this script to open a file to read out a list formatted like so:

test12.someother
test78.someother
test1014.othersome
test101.someotherother

However, when I do a line-by-line execute, I get this error

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "delete_custom_device.py", line 11, in 
deletelist = [x for x in inf.read('\n') if x]
TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not 'str'*

```
import getpass
import customlib

username = getpass.getuser()
password = getpass.getpass()

cdevice = customlib.Session(username, password)
with open('deletefromcustom_test') as inf:
    deletelist = [x for x in inf.read() if x]

errorlist = []
for element in deletelist:
    try:
        custom.deleteDeviceByName(element)
    except:
        errorlist.append(element)
print('These devices that had issues:')
for x in errorlist:
    print(x)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the code you posted, and the error you claim you received. Are you sure you aren't executing an older version of your code by mistake?

Comment: try `inf.readlines()`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a bundle pjk! Paul, by the way, I agree, it is an odd error to get here...